# Why does indexing a binary string return an integer in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary

If given a binary string in python like

```py
bstring = b'hello'
```

why does `bstring[0]` return the ascii code for the char 'h' (104) and not the binary char `b'h'` or `b'\x68'`?

It's probably also good to note that `b'h' == 104` returns `False` (this cost me about 2 hours of debugging, so I'm a little annoyed)

Comment: It is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) in the paragraph that starts with "*While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers...*"

Answer (score 3):

Because bytes are not characters.

It returns the value of the byte (as integer) that is sliced.

If you take 'hello', this is quite simple: 5 ASCII characters -> 5 bytes:

```
b'hello' == 'hello'.encode('utf-8')
# True

len('hello'.encode('utf-8'))
# 5
```

If you were to use non-ASCII characters, those could be encoded on several bytes and slicing could give you only part of a character:

```
len('å'.encode('utf-8'))
# 2

'å'.encode('utf-8')[0]
# 195

'å'.encode('utf-8')[1]
# 165
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of `bytes` less as a “string” and more of an immutable list (or `tuple`) with the constraints that all elements be integers `in range(256)`.

So, think of:

```
>>> bstring = b'hello'
>>> bstring[0]
104
```

as being equivalent to

```
>>> btuple = (104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
>>> btuple[0]
104
```

except with a different sequence type.

It's actually `str` that behaves weirdly in Python.  If you index a `str`, you don't get a `char` object like you would in some other languages; you get another `str`.

```
>>> string = 'hello'
>>> string[0]
'h'
>>> type(string[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> string[0][0]
'h'
>>> string[0][0][0]
'h'
```